# Problem with Unity and C#. Script error. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVnGZ.jpg)So I have started to make a game (With very limited knowledge) using Unity.

Its a 2D game. I have created a script which is for health, food .. ETC..

As soon as I try to load this into unity It comes up with the following error?

'Can't add script component 'Game Manag' because the script class cannot be found. Make sure that there are no compile errors and that the file name and class name match.'

Any Ideas?

https://i.imgur.com/mhEodFW.jpg

[image]

Comment: So have you done what the error is telling you?

Comment: Did you mean to include a space in your script name? "Game Manag" isn't a valid C# class name, whereas `GameManag` or (better) `GameManager` are both valid names. It would really help if you showed the script - at least the declaration.

Comment: as @JonSkeet mentioned, that could be the problem. Show your script.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I uploaded it a few minutes ago. I have included the link in the description. https://i.imgur.com/mhEodFW.jpg

Comment: 'Can't add script component 'Game Manag' because the script class cannot be found. Make sure that there are no compile errors **and that the file name and class name match**.'. Also no need to take a photo of your screen, you can simply copy + paste your code.

Comment: Just a sidenote: rather directly initialize your fields e.g. `int Health = 100;` .. no need to do so in `Start` for private fields ...

Comment: Please show code as *text* rather than screenshots or (worse) photos of screens. But `GameManag` isn't the same as `Game Manag`, which is what it looks like the problem is.

Comment: By the way, find the Print Screen button on your keyboard (or look for Snip in the start menu). Both of those will take screenshots and you don't have to use your phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright looks like you have quite a few errors in your code. You must post your code here, do not post a screenshot. Firstly I would say create a new script with name `GameManager`. Make sure there are no spaces between Game and Manager. Secondly, your `Debug.Log` is throwing errors as well.

I have corrected those errors and posted your error-free code below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
    int Health;
    int Day;
    int Food;
    int Money;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Health = 100;
        Food = 100;
        Day = 0;
        Money = 0;

        Debug.Log(Health);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I will try that once I get home. I shall in future post my code instead of a screenshot. Thank you everyone for your help. :)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you all, once again.

Comment: @DavidBill7 upvote and accept the answer if it helped.